# Power Function Normal Population

Tags: r, statistics, normal-distribution, standardized

I am looking to calculate the power function from a normal population with mean μ and known variance σ².

I'm trying to modify the "help" code:

```
## Power at mu=105 for H0:mu=100 vs. H1:mu>100 (sigma=15) 20 obs. (alpha=0.05) 
   sigma<-1
   c<-0
   mu<-0
   d<-(mu-c)/sigma
   pwr.norm.test(d=d,n=20,sig.level=0.05,alternative="greater")
```

For my test, the alternative is greater than 0 (c=0). I do not have numeric values for the mean and variance.

I also found a function "power.z.test" but the package is appears unavailable for R 3.6.1.

Comment: So you want to do a power calculation without specifying the mean and variance?

Comment: @Dason Yes. I want to specify the sample size and alpha only. Is this possible?

Comment: No. It isn't possible.